# Is it possible to attach a file to an email I want to send with firebase using the trigger email extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I want to use the new 
[firebase email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email/).

I need to attach a file stored in firebase storage to the email. Im browsing [source code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-send-email/functions/src/index.ts) of the extension and I dont see any mention of attachment. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That extension currently doesn't do anything with attachments.  You are welcome to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if that's important to you.